# elm327 CAN command to switch headlights pernament ON

Tags: command, obd-ii, can-bus, elm327

I want to send AT command to switch my headlights pernament ON in Nissan Leaf.

It is located in ID 625

```
0x00 - OFF
0x60 - ON
0x40 - Parking lights ON
0x68 - Headlights & fog lights ON
```

how to change this by sending commands through Terminal 
Can you help step by step?

Comment: Where did you find those ID's? Can you give us a resource?

Answer (score 3):

If your Nissan is talking CAN (i.e. your ELM 327 device will reply with a number between 6 and 9 when you send `AT DPN`), then you can:

`AT Z
AT E0
AT L1
AT SP 0
0100
AT SH 625`

Up to here you have:

1. reset the chipset (`AT Z`)
2. stopped it from echoing back whatever you write (`AT E0`)
3. turned line endings on, so its reply doesn't overwrite your command in temrinal (`AT L1`)
4. set protocol to "auto" (`AT SP 0`)
5. initialize the bus (`0100`) (okay, not really, but this helps the chipset determine the protocol)
6. set the CAN message header to 625 (`AT SH 625`)

Now, do you know which of the bytes do you have to change to 0x40 to turn headlights on? You could try to send `40 00` directly, but I really doubt it helps.

**Note**: don't try to send CAN messages on the buss unless you know what you are doing. Don't hold anybody liable if your car starts acting weird. Also, don't send messages while driving.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it myself with an *ATSH 625* and then sending `02 40`.
However, I found that the 625 is giving a response to the light command and it is not a command. The command is *ATSH 60D*, press Enter to get OK and then send `04 00 00 00 00`.

The below responses have been validated on a Nissan Sunny 2016.

```
0x00 - OFF
0x60 - ON
0x40 - Parking lights ON
```

`60D 04 00 00 00 00` actually turns the parking lights on and it goes off immediately as the key position of your light knob will be at off position unless you change it.

Immediately after sending the above command, I got a response saying `625 02 40 FF`. If your aim is to read the status, monitoring `625` will give that you, for controlling the lights more reverse engineering is required.

I am myself stuck trying to control the door lock/unlock,
I have the response for that, but I have not been able to control it yet.