# Headlight status with OBD-II

Tags: obd-ii

I'm developing an Android app that uses an ELM327 device for OBD-II communications, and I'd like to be able to get the status of the headlights. Specifically, I would like to know if the driver has turned them on or not, but it would also be moderately useful to be able to tell what lights are on (mains vs brights vs DRLs and so on) and whether or not any of the bulbs are out. I was under the impression that there were ways of figuring out whether the headlights were on over OBD-II, but I can't find anything to confirm that, and the API I'm using (the [pires obd-java-api on Github](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api)) doesn't have anything in it either. Can I actually do any of this?

Comment: What specific vehicle are you trying to determine this for?

Comment: I'd like for it to apply to as many vehicles as possible. Mine in particular is an Audi TT

Comment: AFAIK, Headlight messages aren't standardized so you'll have trouble accomplishing this. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26277540/2350083) contains instructions to switch the headlights on a Nissan Leaf. (but not read their state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the standardized OBD PIDs are within [ISO 15031-5](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50816) standard. Some part of it can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) and [here](http://www.geekmyride.org/wiki/index.php/OBD-II_PIDs) as well. All the other PIDs are vehicle specific PIDs which you cannot generalized (or even find) them.

The PIDs that you are searching for might not be standard or supported by every vehicle.